# C++: Nested template classes error "explicit specialization in non-namespace scope"

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

The following code:

```
template <class T1>
struct A1
{
  template <int INDEX>
  struct A2 { /* ... */ };

  template <>
  struct A2<-1> { /* ... */ };
};

int main() 
{
  A1<int>::A2<-1> x;
}
```

Gives this error:

> prog.cpp:7:13: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope `'struct A1<T1>'` 
>      prog.cpp:8:10: error: template parameters not used in partial specialization:
>      prog.cpp:8:10: error:         `'T1'`

How do I work around this error best? I tried this:

```
template <class T1>
struct A1
{
  template <int INDEX, class DUMMY = void>
  struct A2 { /* ... */ };

  template <class DUMMY>
  struct A2<-1, DUMMY> { /* ... */ };
};

int main() 
{
  A1<int>::A2<-1> x;
}
```

Which seems to work but also seems like a bit of a fudge.

Is there a better way of working around this?

I have looked through previous answers and could only find ones with functions in classes, not classes in classes. I also found the "DUMMY" trick in other answers but was wondering if there is a nicer solution.

Also, as a side note, is the first code allowed by C++0x?

Comment: Template specializations have to be at namespace scope, so the compiler is expecting you to do something like `template<typename T> struct A1<T>::A2<-1> { };` after the struct A1 definition, but that doesn't work either. I'm very interested to see an answer to this. On a sidenote, Visual C++ does allow your code, but it is not valid standard C++.

Answer (score 11):

It is not allowed to explicitly specialize `A2` without specializing `A1` (§14.7.3/18). C++0x has the same restriction (n3242 §14.7.3/16). At the same moment a partial specialization of a nested class is allowed. So the trick with a dummy class is Ok.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind the standard not allowing such code? Since otherwise there is a compiler error, why wouldn't the standard instead direct the compiler to effectively insert the "DUMMY" templates itself?

Comment: @Clinton, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537716/why-is-partial-specialziation-of-a-nested-class-template-allowed-while-complete) question.