# C++ templates and union

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, unions

I have some errors when I ported code from MS VS to GCC.

```
template<size_t NB>
union TUnionBlock
{

    template<size_t I = 0>
    class Unroll
    {
    ....
    };

    template<>  // error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘union TUnionBlock<NB>’. unexpected token: >
    class Unroll<NB> // error: template parameters not used in partial specialization: error:         ‘NB’
    {
    ....
    };

};
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Add the relevant information to the question.

Comment: This might be useful information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6302040/434551.