# Specialization of template type dependant structure in a template

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to create a partly specialized member of a templated class, where the inner class's template type is the one coming from the outer class... the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct Num
{
    template <T n>
    struct VH
    {
        enum { value = n };
        T v = value;
    };
};

template <typename T> struct Num<T>::VH<0>
{
    enum {value = 1};
    T v = value;
};

template <typename T> struct Num<T>::VH<1>
{
    enum {value = 0};
    T v = value;
};
```

fails with

```
error: too few template-parameter-lists
     template <typename T> struct Num<T>::VH<0>
```

and the following:

```
template <typename T> struct Num<T>::template<> VH<0>
{
    enum {value = 0};
    T v = value;
};

template <typename T> struct Num<T>::template<> VH<1>
{
    enum {value = 1};
    T v = value;
};
```

just does not feel right (`error: expected template-id before '<' token
     template <typename T> struct Num<T>::template<> VH<0>`)

and after reading
[explicit specialization of template class member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512910/explicit-specialization-of-template-class-member-function)
the following

```
template <typename T> template<> struct Num<T>::VH<0>
{
    enum {value = 0};
    T v = value;
};

template <typename T> template <> struct Num<T>::VH<1>
{
    enum {value = 1};
    T v = value;
};
```

gives the error:

```
error: invalid explicit specialization before '>' token
 template <typename T> template<> struct Num<T>::VH<0>
                                ^
error: enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized
error: template parameters not used in partial specialization:
 template <typename T> template<> struct Num<T>::VH<0>
                                                 ^
error:         'T'
```

Can anyone let me know the correct syntax for this, I don't seem to be able to figure it out now ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax would be

```
template <typename T>
template <>
struct Num<T>::VH<0>
{
    enum {value = 1};
    T v = value;
};
```

But unfortunately, it is not possible to fully specialize a inner struct.
But you can partially specialize it:

With

```
template<typename T>
struct Num
{
    template <T n, int dummy = 0> // Add extra dummy for partial specialization
    struct VH
    {
        enum { value = n };
        T v = value;
    };
};
```

Do

```
template <typename T>
template <int dummy>
struct Num<T>::VH<0, dummy>
{
    enum {value = 1};
    T v = value;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f038845508003fb5)

Comment: Indded, great answer! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537716/why-is-partial-specialziation-of-a-nested-class-template-allowed-while-complete has a detailed explanation. Thanks a lot!